# get Facebook photodetails from photo-id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the facebook photo details, from its id.

1. Currently, am uploading a picture in FB App Album.
2. After successful upload, getting uploaded photo-id

Now how will I get the uploaded-photo-path from its photo-id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is query the [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{photo_id}
```

Comment: please explain what the photo id is, or how to find it

Comment: @mwallisch - the photo id is a unique identifier of the photo resource. It is retrieved via the API.

Comment: alright, that was frustration setting in yesterday. will remove my down-vote as soon as stackoverflow lets me. however if you could give an example of how to retrieve the photo id (e.g. of a posting), that would be great.

Comment: @mwallisch - i appreciate your honesty. You won't be able to remove your vote until the answer is edited.

Comment: The official examples in the Facebook api documentation is the best way to see a working example. Also the "api explorer" is a great place to play with the api and to learn how to use it.